# On WSO2 Implicit flow failing but works for Authorization flow

Tags: wso2, access-token, implicit

I started to learn OpenId Connect from scratch. It's a steep learning curve. I have been working for months with WSO2 as my identity server. Also been experimenting with Thinktecture's IdentityServer 3 which is a C# based open solution. 
I set up a Microsoft Client in C# and it works great with Authorization Code Grant("Authorization") on WSO2.
Then I set up the Implicit Code Flow Grant("Implicit").
The access_token returned looks good. I extracted it from the "hash" segment with a javascript page. However, when I try to use it as Bearer token in the Authorization Header of the Implicit request for claims, it throws the following error as the response.

StatusCode: 500, ReasonPhrase: 'Internal Server Error', Version: 1.1,      Content: System.Net.Http.StreamContent, Headers:
{
  Vary: Accept-Encoding
  Connection: close
  Date: Mon, 16 Mar 2015 13:14:47 GMT
  Server: WSO2
  Server: Carbon
  Server: Server
  Content-Length: 6068
  Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
}

It looks like the access_token from Implicit is defective.

If I substitute a copy of the access_code from an Authorization execution into the final access of the Implicit, as a string literal, it works perfectly.
Any ideas would be welcome.
I have both solutions at
[www.portal-alpha.US](http://www.portal-alpha.US) for Authorization and
[www.portal-omega.US](http://www.portal-omega.US) for Implicit

Any ideas would be helpful.

Comment: I further refined the problem. The Authorization program for both Authentication and Implicit is nearly identical, The major difference I see is solely in the WSO2 Admin where my two sites are selected as "Code" and "Implicit" respectively and the  respective call types are response_type=code and response_type=token. The Implicit flow actually causes a fault on the Tomcat 7 server. Code flow works perfectly.